# Picture in PictureBox isn't shown (C# WIN FORMS)

Tags: c#, picturebox

(I'm using C# with WinForms).

It doesn't show a picture in my picturebox,
instead a blank space appears.

Why doesn't it work ?

(the file is located in the correct folder).

this is my code :

```
public void AddMenuButtons() // Add menu button to all of my tabs
    {
        foreach (TabPage tabPge in tabPcStore.TabPages)
        {
            PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();

            pic.Name = "picboxUser1";
            pic.ImageLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\KfirPicture.png";
            pic.Location = new Point(1, 10);
            pic.Click += new EventHandler(this.picboxUser_Click);
            tabPge.Controls.Add(pic);

        }
    }
```

I've attached photos :

[button before press - it shows a blank space](http://image.prntscr.com/image/3337842e61dd414ab7722a7adc3c9f52.png)

[button after press - context menu appears](http://image.prntscr.com/image/d1d7a9e8d6624777925cc052941a59d1.png)

Comment: I think you have not set your picture box size.

Comment: Thre is an 'issue' with doing things on tabpages other than the selected one. Adding `tabPcStore.SelectedTab =tabPge; ` should fix it, albeit with some flickering..

Comment: Application.StartupPath + @"\KfirPicture.png" is a valid path? Does image exist there? Did you debug and check if the path created is a valid path and image is located there?

Comment: Thanks a lot friends , your advice helped, It works

Comment: Which advice did???

Comment: The advice of o_weisman